# Query sum with distant foreign key relations in Django

Tags: django

Let's say I have models like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...

class Item(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="items")
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Order(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name="orders")
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I now want to get a list of `Product` annotated with the field `total_supply`. "Total supply" is defined for each product as: (sum of all of a product's items' `quantity`) - (sum of `quantity` on all of the Order objects associated with one of the product's items.)

Here is what I have tried:

`Product.objects.annotate(actual_supply=Sum("items__quantity") - Sum("items__orders__quantity"))`

I am getting unexpected results. How am I supposed to write such a query?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not really following what the use is of `Item`, and not store `quantity` on the `Product` model, or if that is necessary for "incoming" transfers, why the `item` in the `Order` referes to `Product`.

Comment: The actual use case is a bit more complicated than I presented here. You are right about the "incoming transfers" though, basically when an order is pending (hasn't been shipped yet), I don't want to adjust the quantity on the other model, but I still want the inventory stock to reflect that the ordered amount is unavailable. There is probably a bit of code smell here though...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you here make *two* `JOIN`s, so that means that for each `Order`, it will add the `quantity` of the `item`, so the same amount is added multiple times.

This thus means that if you have one `Item` with `quantity=5`, and two orders with `quantity=1` and `quantity=2`, one would expect that the result is `2`, but because that `Item` is summed up two times, the result will be `7`.

One could work with a subquery here to avoid that effect, like:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Product.objects.annotate(
    actual_supply=Subquery(
        Item.objects.filter(
            product_id=OuterRef('pk')
            .values('product_id')
            .values(a=Sum('quantity'))
            .order_by('product_id')[:1]
        )
    )
    - Sum('items__orders__quantity')
)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! This looks like it is working well. My only question is what the slice at the end of the subquery is doing? The [:1]